# QGIS 2.14 vectorgrid function fails in a custom application

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

The vectorgrid function works in the QGIS Python console. However, if I would like to run it outside of QGIS in a custom application, it fails. Here is what I do. First I set up the environment:

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
@echo off
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\bin
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\python;
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr
python
```

Secondly, I run following lines in Python:

```
import os, sys
from qgis.core import *
from osgeo import ogr
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.gui import *
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr', True)
app = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
sys.path.append(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing
processing.runalg("qgis:vectorgrid", "0, 1, 0, 1", "0.5", "0.5", "0", None)
```

This yields following message:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mapCanvas'
See log for more details
{'OUTPUT': u'C:\\Users\\pi37pat\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\processingb5f3676e719f400a9c4b0a135e1cbb89\\dd1a9527b3e04e03b956a396dcd3e76b\\OUTPUT.shp'}
```

Unfortunately, the indicated output file does not exist. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your slashes in QgsApplication.setPrefixPath are going the wrong way.  You should change the slashes or add and "r" value before the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the `qgis:vectorgrid` algorithm requires you to set up map canvas as described in this post: [Need help getting started with QgsComposition](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28688/need-help-getting-started-with-qgscomposition).

There is another algorithm called `qgis:creategrid` which also allows you to create a grid but also assign a CRS to it, this should not produce the map canvas error.

So you could replace the last two lines:

```
import processing
processing.runalg("qgis:vectorgrid", "0, 1, 0, 1", "0.5", "0.5", "0", None)
```

with this:

```
from processing.tools import *
general.runalg("qgis:creategrid", 1, "0, 1, 0, 1", "0.5", "0.5", "EPSG:4236", None)
```

---

This worked for me (whilst changing the PATHS to fit my environment):

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, Joseph! However, your suggestion still produces the exact same message (`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mapCanvas'`) and still no output...

Comment: @Jannes - Most welcome, edited the post to offer a slight alternative :)

Comment: Thank you very much again, I do appreciate your efforts! The `creategrid`-function works! Now I am only a little bit curious how many more QGIS-functions require the mapCanvas or something alike which would make them harder to use in a custom application...

Comment: @Jannes - No problem, I like problem-solving questions like these! I doubt there's many as I have used quite a few in scripts without that error popping up.